# Deletion of duplicate records using one query only

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am using SQL server 2005.

I have a table like this -

```
ID    Name
1      a
1      a
1      a
2      b
2      b
3      c
4      d
4      d
```

In this, I want to delete all duplicate entries and retain only one instance as -

```
ID     Name
1       a
2       b
3       c
4       d
```

I can do this easily by adding another identity column to this table and having unique numbers in it and then deleting the duplicate records. However I want to know if I can delete the duplicate records **without adding that additional column** to this table.

Additionally if this can be done using only one query statement. i.e. **Without using Stored procedures or temp tables.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using a [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) in a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) allows you to delete duplicate values while retaining unique rows.

```
WITH q AS (
  SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID )
         , ID
         , Name
  FROM   ATable
)
DELETE FROM q WHERE RN > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Lieven is Right... however you may want to tweak lieven's code by just adding a top clause in the delete statement like this:

delete top(1) from q where RN > 1;

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You may use this query:

```
delete a from
(select id,name, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id,name order by id) row_Count
from dup_table) a
where  a.row_Count >1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
delete from table1
USING table1, table1 as vtable
WHERE (NOT table1.ID=vtable.ID)
AND (table1.Name=vtable.Name)
```

Comment: Are you sure USING is available in SQL server? I am getting syntax error near USING.

Comment: sorry, I have tested it for MySQL, I thought it works on SQL as well. What error do you get?

Comment: No problem, I get incorrect syntax near USING. I dont think there is any USING keywork in SQL. It will be converted to FROM.

Answer (score -1):

```
DELETE FROM tbl
WHERE ID NOT IN (
    SELECT MIN(ID)
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY Name
)
```

Comment: Just to mention, I did not downvote you. But the IDs are same for duplicate rows too. However,

Comment: this will delete all records with an ID <> 1, not what OP needs. (not my downvote btw).